# Change data source dynamically on user login

Tags: spring, security, thread-safety, ejb

I have a project that has the following requeriments:

1. Allow users to login in the same Web Application using different schemas following a criteria;
2. Dynamically route the datasource against a rule - for example, users in Company A should access schema A, users in Company B should access schema B;
3. The business logic which authenticates the user`s should be in a business component - EJB, because new applications can be added and this logic must be outside the Web Application.

I read about using [Dynamic Data Source Routing](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/). The `CustomerContextHolder` has a field which is `ThreadLocal`. Is `ThreadLocal` a guarantee that the user A will access the schema A following my criteria? Will the code be thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand is that you need multi tenency for spring along with datasource.

Probably you have have a look to spring extension which might help

https://github.com/mariofts/spring-multitenancy